# select mysql by Opposite

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i need my php
to select some data from table by Opposite

like if i have tablhe have id like that

1
2
3
5

> i need to show it like that

5
3
2
1
by select query

this is my code (not full)

in tech.php

```
<?PHP require_once('post_technology.php'); ?>
<?PHP $posts= post_technology::find_all();  ?>    
<?PHP foreach($posts as $post): ?>
<!--start post -->
<div class="item">
<h2><a href="technology_post.php?id=<?PHP echo $post->id; ?>"><?PHP echo $post->post_name; ?></a></h2>
<div class="info">
<span class="date"><?PHP echo $post->post_time; ?></span>
<span class="author">by <?PHP echo $post->post_user; ?></span>
<a href="technology_post.php?id=<?PHP echo $post->id; ?>" class="comments">comments</a>
</div>
<a href="technology_post.php?id=<?PHP echo $post->id; ?>"><img src="<?PHP if($post->post_photo == "post_img/"){echo ".\images\no-photo.jpg";}else{ echo $post->post_photo; } ?>" alt="" width="850" height="250" class="image" /></a>
<p><?PHP echo $post->post_e5tsar; ?></p>
<p class="last"><a href="technology_post.php?id=<?PHP echo $post->id; ?>" class="more-link"><span>Read more</span></a></p>
<!-- END .item -->
</div>
<!-- end al post -->
<?php endforeach ; ?>
```

post_technology.php :

```
class post_technology {
    protected static $table_name="post_technology";
    protected static $db_fields=array('id', 'post_name', 'post_user', 'post_time', 'post_photo', 'post_e5tsar', 'post_full', 'post_table');
    public $id;
    public $post_name;
    public $post_user;
    public $post_time;
    public $post_photo;
    public $post_e5tsar;
    public $post_full;
    public $post_table;
    public $errors=array();


  public static function find_by_id($id=0) {
    $result_array = self::find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM ".self::$table_name." WHERE id={$id}  LIMIT 1");
        return !empty($result_array) ? array_shift($result_array) : false;
  }

  public static function find_by_sql($sql="") {
    global $database;
    $result_set = $database->query($sql);
    $object_array = array();
    while ($row = $database->fetch_array($result_set)) {
      $object_array[] = self::instantiate($row);
    }
    return $object_array;
  }
```

this is my code
it post in tec.php
hop it to post the new posts first

Comment: There's only one query which is restricted to a specific id and a limit of 1. To reach your aim you have to call find_by_sql with a query like the one i posted. If you like to get the top 5 ids, just add the LIMIT 5 to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: no it's not work with me ... i will show some of my code to you

Comment: alright, and please say what is not working, or what the query returns and what you expect it to return.